# unable to draw multiple datatables on single page with custom inputs, How to make it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have 3 or more DataTables in my single page link below. i am using custom filter input for all DataTables.

[Click Here for page](http://image.webspapa.in/test.php)

```
or copy this url -  http://image.webspapa.in/test.php
```

This is working fine for 2nd and 3rd table but

- whenever i filter first table , all the three got filtered. whats wrong in 
  this ?
- Second why i am unable access variable `dataTabel` value in my second `$(function(){})`(console showing it undefined)  while i have already defined it as global scope

  ```
  var dataTabel;
  $(function() {
      var dataTabel = $('.dataTable').DataTable({"dom": 't<"bottom"ip><"clear">'});
      $('.panel-heading input').keyup(function(){
          var Tabel = $('.panel-heading input').index($(this));
          dataTabel.tables(Tabel).search($(this).val()).draw();
      });
  });
  $(function(){
      console.log(dataTabel);
  });
  ```

  please See my full code in link provided, and help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple confusion of scopes. `dataTabel` is only available inside the self invoking function itself, why use that anyway, why even use `$(function() {...`? What extra should the `$` provide? It does not make sanse. Remove the repeated `var`'s, you only want to declare `dataTabel` once, remove all those self invoking functions, they have no purpose or meaning, what so ever.

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks for your response, actually code provided above belongs to three files included with the help of php. First `$(function() {...` is in inlcude.php file and second one in the main test.php file. i have also some stuff to do with that var in main file.